# Refreshing Discord Bot's Activity Upon Being Added To A Server

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a discord bot where its activity is set like below

```
module.exports = (client) => {
  console.log(`${client.user.username} ✅`) 
  const activities = [
    `Music Videos`,
    `*help`,
    `In ${client.guilds.cache.size} Servers`,
    `Support Server ====> discord.gg/ZJevrUQ46Q`
  ];
  
  let i = 0;
  setInterval(() => client.user.setActivity(`${activities[i++ % activities.length]}`, { type: 'PLAYING' }), 5000);
  

}
```

Is there any way for me to update its server count when it's added to a new server?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you just call set interval again in the mainloop? or on a schedule?

Comment: You could consider using the `Client#guildCreate` event and update it accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `Client#guildCreate` event would make this more convenient to achieve. The event would only emit whenever a client joins a guild, whether it's created its own, or gets invited onto a server.

This should work:

```js
client.on('guildCreate', guild => {
    const activities = [
        `Music Videos`,
        `*help`,
        `In ${client.guilds.cache.size} Servers`,
        `Support Server ====> discord.gg/ZJevrUQ46Q`,
        `Most recently added to ${guild.name}` //a nice bonus feature!
    ];

    let i = 0;
    setInterval(() => client.user.setActivity(`${activities[i++ % activities.length]}`, { type: 'PLAYING' }), 5000);
});
```

Comment: Well your status seems to loop forever, so it should theoretically work just fine.